# Infinite memory when declaring a object of a class inside the same class

Tags: java, class, object, memory

```
class firsttry{
    public static void main(String [] args){
       int a=10;
       firsttry first = new firsttry();
       first.calculate(a);

    }       


    public void calculate(int b){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){  
            System.out.println(b);
            b+=10;  
        }

    }

}
```

I had run the program and it runs fine. I was wondering how come this is possible. Doesn't it allocate infinite memory. `"first"` object itself has `"first"` object within it and so on. Please explain.

Comment: try to eleborate what you want to ask first object itself has first object  what do you mean to say by this line???

Comment: Please use spaces instead of tabs to format code on Stack Overflow - and pay attention to the preview before posting. Your code is currently very hard to read. Additionally, following normal naming conventions even for sample code makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`main` is a static method, so it does not need any object instance of type `firsttry` (i.e. no object of type `firsttry` is created). In particular, `main` is **not** called when you create a new object of type `firsttry`, so the `new` call only is executed once.

If you had `new firsttry(..)` in a constructor of the class `firsttry`, there would indeed be the danger that this is executed an `infinite` amount of times.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's totally normal. Look:

You run `static main`. You do not have Instance right now.

You create an instance of `firsttry`, then you call `calculate` which has an end condition on its loop. `main` method will not be called when you instanciate `firsttry`. This is not a constructor but a `static` method.

So, it will run the loop then stop. That's normal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want to ask but I think you're confused between a static method and an object. `main()` is a static method which does not require instantiation. Moreover, if you are confused with:

```
firsttry first = new firsttry();
```

then:

```
firsttry first;
```

is the declaration and:

```
first = new firsttry();
```

is the instantiation.